# Is it possible to generate a load at constant intervals using precise throughput timer or constant throughput timer?

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to achieve a throughput of 600 requests per hour for a particular API request. There is only 1 user. I tried Precise Throughput timer which has generated the required numbers but the requests are fired at random interval because I guess it works on Poisson arrival pattern. I tried replacing 0 for ‘Random Seed’ setting with a positive integer like value 1 to generate requests at a constant interval. But it is still does not make any difference. Can this be achieved using Constant Throughput timer?
Any suggestion would be helpful.

I tried using Precise Throughput timer by changing the values like:

1. Target Throughput of 600 for a Throughput period of 3600 sec
2. Target Throughput of 10 for a Throughput period of 60 sec
3. Tried random seed values 0 for random and 1 for constant

Above changes didn’t make any difference and the requests were fired at random interval instead of constant interval

Answer (score 0):

Constant Throughput Timer will fire the requests in more or less equal intervals. As you can see a request is being executed each 6 seconds:

[image]

You can achieve equal intervals (without "more or less") only if your response time will be the same or similar all the time, no matter which timer you're using, Constant Throughput, Precise Throughput, [Throughput Shaping](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) or [implement pacing manually](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/implement-pacing-jmeter).